# complexity analysis of algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory

here is code, which fills  two dimensional array with random genarated numbers in range [1 19] without duplication, my question is: how to determine it's complexity?

For example, I see that its running time is at least O(n^2), because of its inner and outer cycles, but that about the `goto` statement?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int min=1;
    int max=19;
    int  a[3][3];
    set<int>b;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
loop:
            int m=min+rand()%(max-min);

            if (b.find(m)==b.end())
            {
                a[i][j]=m;
                b.insert(m);
            }
            else
                goto loop;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
            cout<< a[i][j]<<"  ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I  would say that complexity of algorithm is c*O(n^2) where c is some constant, it is because if it finds duplicated element inside cycles it repeats generation of random numbers and takes some constant time, am I right?

Comment: Also, please fix the indenting in your code.  It's very hard to read.

Comment: It's a `goto` statement. RUN!

Comment: you could use a vector of number and take (and remove) one so you can know the complexity of your algorithm. With your actual version, the complexity of your algorithm is at worse infinity...

Comment: It makes no sense to say c*O(something), since the O(something) already means that some multiplicative constant is involved.

Comment: "for example, i see, that at least it's running time is O(n^2) because of it's inner and outer cycles" don't make the assumption that two nested cycles implies O(N^2).

Comment: This is a perfect example of a really bad shuffle algorithm. Don't bother with this method, change to Fished-Yates method; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: By the way, that `goto` can be replaced simply with a `j--`.

Comment: To be clear: it's currently impossible to say what the complexity is, because you haven't made it clear what `n` corresponds to.

Comment: If you assume your cost to be constant, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant

Comment: n corresponds to 3  or dimension  of row  or column of matrix,as you like

Comment: @user: no, no, no, you need N to be variable.

Comment: Well, technically, it would be O(3x3) then, which is just O(1). But I'm inclined to think that `max=19` is another candidate. On average (and I'm intentionally using that word), it takes more time if `max` is smaller, and the algorithm takes an infinite amount of time when `max < 3*3`.

Comment: guys  first of all thanks  everybody,sure i have seen  these algorithms like Fisher–Yates shuffle or others.i used this method because it is simple and also i have exam  in a few days in university(at master program),and complexity here does not matter,just i was curious,but again i will consider all your's advise and never use it  next time.thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the likelihood of getting a working number decreases, the number of goto-loops increases.
For a uniform random number generator, the behavior is linear with respect to the number of.. numbers. It definitely doesn't add a constant to your complexity.

If n is the number of elements in a, then it'll on average scale with O(n²). (or if n is the number of rows in the square matrix a; O(n⁴)).

A much simpler implementation would be using [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: This critically depends on `max` versus `N`. If `max` grows as O(N*N), then the average number of goto loops doesn't grow. And obviously, if `max` doesn't grow at all, then the algorithm breaks when `N*N > max`. You can't fill a 5x5 matrix with only 20 unique numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It's O(infinity). The O notation gives an upper bound. Because of your use of `rand()` in a loop, there's no guarantee that you will make progress. Therefore, no upper bound exists.

[edit]
Ok, people also want other complexities than the conventional, worst-case complexity.

The worst-case complexity obtained by assuming that the RNG generates an infinite series of ones; this means that even the first loop iteration doesn't finish. Therefore there's no finite upper bound on the run time, O(infinity).

The best-case complexity is obtained by assuming that the RNG generates sequential numbers. That means the cost of each iteration is O(log N) (`set::find`), and there are O(N)*O(N) iterations, so the upper bound is O(N<sup>2</sup> log N).

The average case complexity is harder. Assuming that `max = k*N*N` for some `k` > 1, the RNG will succesfully pick an "unused" number in O(1) time. Even after N*N numbers are chosen, there are still (k-1) unused numbers, so the chance *p* of picking an unused number is `p >= (k-1)*(N*N)/k*(N*N) <=> p>= (k-1)/k`. That means we can expect to pick an unused number in `k/(k-1)` attempts, which is independent of N and therefore O(1). `set::find` still dominates the cost of each iteration, at O(log N). We still have the same number of iterations, so we get the same upper bound of O(N<sup>2</sup> log N)

Comment: Big-O does not mean "worst-case".  It is, however, fair to say "the worst-case complexity is O(infinity)".

Comment: It does mean upper bound, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations . Lower bound is `Ω(f(N))`, combined bound is `Θ(f(N))`

Comment: Damn, you were faster than me. +1 anyway.

Comment: There's a difference between "worst-case" and "upper bound". You can have a lower bound on the worst case or an upper bound on the best case etc.

Comment: Obviously it only makes sense to talk about average complexity here.  That is still quite a useful metric, even if there are pathological cases where it may not terminate.

Comment: What @quasiverse said.  These are not the same thing.

Comment: @quasiverse: Of course. The [convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Upper_and_lower_bounds_on_the_complexity_of_problems) is that _the_ complexity of an algorithm is the worst-case complexity, and therefore "the O(N) complexity" is "the upper-bound worst-case complexity". The two concepts (which case and which bound) are orthogonal.

Comment: Not going to downvote, but all you have to do is assume that the random number generator is uniform to guarantee convergence in probability.  Furthermore, you can work out the expected complexity.  So I doubt that it's O(infinity)

Comment: @Chris A: That's how you get the upper bound on the _average_ complexity. The upper bound on the best case is even trivial, that's just `O(N*N)` (assuming `a` is an NxN matrix). Just assume the random number generator produces sequential numbers.

Comment: @MSalters, thanks for the clarification.  IMO, the upper bound on the worst case complexity tells you a lot less than the upper bound on the average complexity in this problem.  Especially since very mild (and realistic) assumptions on the RNG make this never happen.

Answer (score 1):

The goto loops until a random number equals a given one.
if the distribution of random numbers is uniform, "retry ... until" is "linear in average" respect to the amplitude of the range.
But this linearity gos to multiply the complexity of set::find (log(n)) (ste::insert just happen once)

The two external for are based on constants (so their timing doesn't depend on the data), hence they just multiply the time, but don't increase complexity.

Answer (score 1):

"Complexity" is not about how much absolute time (or space) your program takes. It is about how much the time (or space) **increases** when you increase the size of your program's input data.

*(BTW O for time and O for space may be different.)*

### Time Complexity

Assuming *n* is number of elements in the matrix, you have to ask yourself what happens when you add a single element to your matrix (i.e. when *n* becomes *n+1*):

- You need to iterate over the new element, which is O(1). We are talking about **one iteration** here, so double loop does not matter.
- You have another iteration for printing, which is also O(1), assuming `cout<<` is O(1).
- You have to `find` the element which is O(log(n)) - the `std::set` is typically implemented as a red-black tree.
- You have to retry the `find` (via `goto`) potentially several times. Depending on `rnd`, `min`, `max` and the width of `int`, number of retries may be O(1) (i.e. it does not increase with increase in number of elements) or it may be worse than that.
- You have to `insert` the element which is O(log(n)).

Assuming the "best" `rnd`, you are looking at the following increase **for one element**...

> (O(1) + O(1)) * (O(log(n)) * O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(1) * O(log(n)) = O(log(n))

...so **for n elements**, your complexity is:

> (O(n) + O(n)) * (O(log(n)) * O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(n) * O(log(n)) = O(n * log(n))

Assuming "bad" `rnd` of O(n), you are looking at...

> (O(n) + O(n)) * (O(log(n)) * O(n) + O(log(n)) = O(n) * O(n * log(n)) = O(n^2 * log(n))

### Space Complexity

Your matrix is O(n) and `std::set` is O(n) so you are O(n) here overall.